# How do I make sure a string only a double of any length?

Tags: java

I need a Regex I think to see if a string is only a double but it can be of any length, any suggestions?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to determine if a call to `Double.parseDouble(...)` will throw an exception?

Comment: I would think, just try doing what Adam said, and handle any exception in the catch..

Comment: The "any length" part seems to indicate he wants to parse an arbitrarily long "nnnnn.nnnE+/-nnnn", and not http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try and convert the string to a double and catch the exception if it fails?

```
try{
  Double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(aString);
}catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
// handle it not being a Double here
}
```

Comment: Generally I consider this an anti-pattern (trying something and then catching the exception if it doesn't work).  But I don't know why -- it's perfectly valid -- I just try to avoid doing it where possible.  Unfortunately I don't think there's a better test here.

Comment: @Tenner you should consider it an anti-pattern, since it means catching exceptions for the purpose of program flow. But I blame the API developers for not including a Double.tryParseDouble() method

Comment: The reason why, is partly due to performance reasons (the time it takes to generate an Exception's stacktrace is nontrivial) and partly conceptual - exceptions should represent *exceptional* circumstances.  Thus it's OK if the input *must* be a double, but not if a non-numeric string counts as a valid input.

Comment: +1, for thinking outside the box and giving an answer that is easily understood rather that depending on some unnecessary regex.

Answer (score 3):

A double would match the following regexp:

```
^[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?$
```

Note that for a Java String you would need to escape the backslashes, and that `\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `^(\d+|\d+\.|\d*\.\d+)[dD]?$`

Answer (score 0):

If I take your meaning correctly, this regular expression might work

```
"/^[+-]?\d+\.\d+$/"
```

In English -> A + or - sign (maybe) followed by one or more digits followed by a . (decimal point) followed by one or more digits. This regular expression assumes that numbers are not formatted with commas and also assumes that the decimal separator is a dot which is not true in all locales.

Answer (score 0):

I stole this expression from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-determine-whether-a-scalar-is-a-number/whole/integer/float?) faq4 -- "is a decimal number".

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pattern pattern = 
                Pattern.compile("^-?(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)$");

            System.out.println(((Boolean) pattern.matcher("1").find()).toString());
            System.out.println(((Boolean) pattern.matcher("1.1").find()).toString());
            System.out.println(((Boolean) pattern.matcher("abc").find()).toString());


        }

    }
```

Prints:

```
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also like to look at the NumberUtils from Apache Commons

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html